# Mongoose + Node.js, Object.assign (copy of data returned from database) shows additional data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Today I found an interesting thing, that I never knew before. I need help in understanding why this happened:

```
User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, usr){
     return res.json({
          RAW: usr,
          COPY: Object.assign({}, usr, {some: 'change'})
     }) 
})
```

This yield

```
{
    "RAW": {
        "createdAt": "2018-06-25T09:16:35.516Z",
        "_id": "5b30b2f36c492c55a818b455",
        "email": "some@email.com",
        "password": "$2b$08$k5IRBF.1i.q.7D/BD4HCVuOdnIRDQOHaT6icNwIyc1XfeklUwyF5.",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "COPY": {
        "$__": {
            "strictMode": true,
            "selected": {},
            "getters": {},
            "_id": "5b30b2f36c492c55a818b455",
            "wasPopulated": false,
            "activePaths": {
                "paths": {
                    "createdAt": "init",
                    "_id": "init",
                    "email": "init",
                    "password": "init",
                    "__v": "init"
                },
                "states": {
                    "ignore": {},
                    "default": {},
                    "init": {
                        "_id": true,
                        "email": true,
                        "password": true,
                        "createdAt": true,
                        "__v": true
                    },
                    "modify": {},
                    "require": {}
                },
                "stateNames": [
                    "require",
                    "modify",
                    "init",
                    "default",
                    "ignore"
                ]
            },
            "pathsToScopes": {},
            "emitter": {
                "domain": null,
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 0,
                "_maxListeners": 0
            },
            "$options": true
        },
        "isNew": false,
        "_doc": {
            "createdAt": "2018-06-25T09:16:35.516Z",
            "_id": "5b30b2f36c492c55a818b455",
            "email": "some@email.com",
            "password": "$2b$08$k5IRBF.1i.q.7D/BD4HCVuOdnIRDQOHaT6icNwIyc1XfeklUwyF5.",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "$init": true,
        "some": "change"
    }
}
```

See the difference between **RAW** and **COPY**. According to my understanding

1. Object.assign() just creates a copy of an Object with the new memory address.
2. Then `RAW.email` should be EQUAL to `COPY.email` (but it's not, WHY?)

Clearly, the `COPY` contains information from MongoDB, if `RAW` already had those data (hidden) then how can `RAW.email` gets the data whereas `COPY.email` is `undefined`.

HOW does this abstraction work in case of `RAW`?

Comment: I think it has got to do with toString function of the mongoose model. It shows only the _doc. But not sure.

Comment: Didn't got you I can see email in COPY._doc.email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Express `res.json` documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) states,

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

And `JSON.stringify` uses [`toJSON` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) where available to get object values. Mongoose documents [support it](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON).

Since `toJSON` isn't own enumerable method of `usr`, it's omitted when it's shallowly copied with `Object.assign({}, usr)`, so the object is treated as is by `JSON.stringify` and internal document properties are exposed.

It likely should be:

```
 res.json({
      RAW: usr,
      COPY: Object.assign({}, usr.toJSON(), {some: 'change'})
 })
```

Comment: Thanks @estus, makes sense. +1